# Парсинг XML документа и получение атрибутов

Tags: php, xml, парсер

Запрашиваю с чужого сервера XML вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><info><u id = "12345"
nickname = "User"
score = "22"
battles = "456"
...
etc
...
     />
```

Необходимо получить доступ к каждому атрибуту u. 
Пытался набросать вариант с simpleXML, но, видимо, руки мои немного не оттуда.

Собственно, прошу помощи в решении данной задачи.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы покажите что у вас за код, а там видно будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<info>
 <u name="one" score = "22" />
 <u name="two" score = "33" />
</info>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($xml as $u) {
    printf("User: %s" .  PHP_EOL);
    echo $u->attributes()->name . PHP_EOL;
    // or 
    foreach($u->attributes() as $key => $value) {
        printf("%s => %s%s", $key, $value, PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. То, что нужно :)

Answer (score 0):

У каждой ноды есть метод attributes(). К нему и обращаемся.

```
foreach($xml->u->attributes() as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: т.е. , внутри цикла теперь , можно, к примеру, через switch() отловить нужную информацию? 

Вариант 


$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
echo $xml->data->u->attributes()->nickname; 

возвращал ошибку, мол, вызов вне объекта.